# Get Contact List From ICloud API

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, icloud

Requesting ICloud API and login by using below URL

```
string url = "https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/login?clientBuildNumber=1P24&clientId=" + RANDOM_GUID;
```

Getting server url and dsid from above url response. 
Further requesting for Contact list by using below  code

```
var localUrl2 = "https://p66-contactsws.icloud.com/co/startup?clientBuildNumber=1P24&clientId=" + RANDOM_GUID + "&clientVersion=2.1&dsid=" + dsid + "&locale=en-EN&order=last%2Cfirst";
var webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(localUrl2);
webRequest2.Method = "GET";
webRequest2.Headers.Set("Origin", "https://www.icloud.com");
// get the X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-TOKEN and X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-USER from  webResponse.Headers.SetCookie
webRequest2.Headers.Set("X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-TOKEN",  XXXXXXX);
webRequest2.Headers.Set("X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-USER",  XXXXXXXX);

WebResponse webResponse2 = webRequest2.GetResponse();
```

Still getting exception

> The remote server returned an error: (421) Misdirected Request.

Please let me know what is wrong in above code.

Comment: Apple may have "shut down" this endpoint, but they do have an official web API you could use [CloudKit documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240).

Comment: Please see my attempts to connect to the iCloud contact server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738343/apple-icloud-access-to-contacts-in-uwp-application). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, Apple has taken the end point you are trying to reach offline hence the 421 error. You can look into another way to accomplish this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240).